# Generate barcode using timestamp and save it into database and display the saved data in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, barcode

I want to generate barcode using timestamp and save it into database and display the saved data in a table. I am successful in generating barcode from controller. I created a separate class BarcodeTagHelper.cs.

**BarcodeTagHelper.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using ZXing;
using BarcodeLib;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace AuthSystem.Tags
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime package into your project
    [Authorize]
    [HtmlTargetElement("barcode")]
    public class BarCodeTagHelper : TagHelper
    {

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var content = context.AllAttributes["content"].Value.ToString();
            var width = int.Parse(context.AllAttributes["width"].Value.ToString());
            var height = int.Parse(context.AllAttributes["height"].Value.ToString());
            var BarcodeWriterPixelData = new BarcodeWriterPixelData
            {
                Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
                Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                {
                    Height = height,
                    Width = width,
                    Margin = 0
                }
            };
            var pixelData = BarcodeWriterPixelData.Write(content);
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height),
                        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                    try
                    {
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
                            .Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixelData.Pixels.Length);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                    output.TagName = "img";
                    output.Attributes.Clear();
                    output.Attributes.Add("width", width);
                    output.Attributes.Add("height", height);
                    output.Attributes.Add("src", String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can use the following code in any controller and generate in any view by providing any random value.

```
public IActionResult Generate(string productId)
        {
            ViewBag.productId = productId;
            return View("Index");
        }
```

following is the view where barcode is being generated

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}


<!---Click button to generate UUID and then copy the --->

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="button" onclick="getElementById('random-number').value = new Date().getTime().toString()">Create Unique ID</button>
<br>
<input id="random-number" value="" />


<!---Click Generate to generate Barcode---->

<form method="post" asp-controller="Courier" asp-action="generate">
    <input type="text" placeholder="productId" name="productId" />
    <input type="submit" value="Generate" />
</form>


<!-----Following code displays barcode and qrcode images in png format----->

@if (ViewBag.productId != null)
{
    <qrcode content="@ViewBag.productId" width="100" height="100" alt="" name="productId" />
    <barcode content="@ViewBag.productId" width="500" height="50" alt="" name="productId" />
}
```

I want to generate barcode and save it into database but this is not as simple as it sounds.

Procedure to save and display barcode in table:

**1. Fill the product description form.**

**2. Submit the form to save data into database.**

**3. Submitting form will generate a UID and Barcode/QR Code from UID.**

**4. Finally Barcode/QR Code will be visible in table content.**

[image]

Comment: Anyone who know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I'm wrong. Are you want a timestamp of when a Barcode/ QR code was scanned?

If it is, A simple solution will be followed.

1. QR/Barcode can hold Url. you can bind your API's Action or Event Emitter to Trigger that event.

Comment: No I need to use the timestamp as a 'Unique Id' and use it to generate Barcode and QR code. The sole purpose of using the timestamp as 'UID' is to generate a short Unique Id to generate a Barcode and QR Code. I am successful in generating timestamp as a UID but failed to generate Barcode/QR code from the generated UID.